# How should we tag questions about the TV show, House of the Dragon?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I've recently asked [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267114/7957) about the TV show, *House of the Dragon*, and [suggested a tag wiki](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/267121/revisions#rev-body-24cadafa-517c-4d57-8ed7-1157cfc9ab00) for [house-of-the-dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-the-dragon). User DavidW  [edited my question to also have](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/267114/revisions#rev-body-7027ce0f-95a6-46bb-a861-80b0e76afb4d) [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) and has [added a tag usage guidance](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/267121/revisions#rev-body-24cadafa-517c-4d57-8ed7-1157cfc9ab00) to [house-of-the-dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-the-dragon):

> Use with the [game-of-thrones] tag.

[My question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267114/7957) is *not* about *Game of Thrones*, and in fact, has nothing to do with it.

One of the suggested edit review queue pre-defined rejection reasons is:

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is *about*, not just what it *contains*.

I would've reverted that tag edit to my question since it doesn't describe what the question is *about*, but then I would go against the tag usage guidance written in the tag wiki. In other SE sites I'm more familiar with, like Arqade, and Movies & TV SE, questions about a sequel or prequel work aren't tagged with the tag of the work it is a sequel or prequel to (unless the question's topic overlaps both works). I'm wondering if it's different in SF&F SE.

---

On the same topic of the *House of the Dragon* TV show tagging, if a [house-of-the-dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-the-dragon) question topic overlaps the books (the question I linked above doesn't), should it also be tagged with [fire-and-blood](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-and-blood) (book the show is based on) and/or [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) (the book series)?

###### How should we tag questions about the TV show, House of the Dragon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*House of the Dragon* is a spinoff of the TV series *Game of Thrones*; the marketing material even mentions *Game of Thrones*. For example, see the below poster:

[image: House of the Dragon poster showing Rhaenerys on the Iron Throne]

I think it's fine if we treat our tags the same and use [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) as a universe tag for the show world *and* for the specific show itself. In that case the tag wiki edit and post edit by DavidW make sense.

This also aligns with how we're treating [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) as the universe tag for the book world. You will see that it is used for questions about the main series and the spin offs such as *Fire and Blood* and *The World of Ice and Fire*.

If your question is overlapping in scope with the books and TV world you are fine to tag with both the universe tags as well as any more specific tags as necessary.

Comment: I see. I thought [[tag:game-of-thrones]] is a TV show tag, when in fact, it is a universe tag. We should edit the [[tag:game-of-thrones]] tag wiki to reflect this tag usage guidance.